# What's the best mechanism for deploying libraries (dll's) centrally, so a dev team can just add reference to them?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, nuget, continuous-deployment

Just curious, per my title above.
I am leaning towards a nuget package-like style, where the dev team can continuously update libraries (dll's) and deploy them to a central location e.g. Nuget. Then, have project reference the dll depending on the version that's been deployed in a central location e.g. Nuget.

Deploying the dll's in a shared folder won't work.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Do you use any CI/CD system or tools like Azure DevOps?

Comment: @hyvte we do... but in DevOps, where does the compiled/deployed dll's get stored? how does the team create reference to any specific version of the library?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, nuget is the best way.

**Pack**

You can work with your teammates to maintain the same nuget project. When you are creating a nuget package or make some changes, you can just set different nuget versions for them to pack them as nuget package(`.nupkg`). These are [different pack functions(non-sdk project uses nuget.exe, new-sdk projects use dotnet cli, msbuild.exe can work with both of them but note in non-sdk projects, it works with non-sdk projects with PackageReference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli).

**Push**

When you finish it, you could push the nuget package into a a shared folder, or [push into an azure devops feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/publish?view=azure-devops).

**Use**

You just send the full path of the shared folder or the feed url link(they should give your teammates sufficient permissions)

And anyone who wants to use it should set the link into [nuget package sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources), and then they can install it to use it.

**Besides**, if there is a subsequent update operation, as a nuget maintainer, you modify the lib project, after that, set a new version for it, [any descriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli#add-an-optional-description-field) to tell others there is a new release updated version during pack process.

**Then**, push the new version into the feed to let others could install it.